# I can't properly define a function in Python. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Tags: python, function

The directions are to:
Write a function called calc_average that takes a string representing a filename of the following format, for example:

```
Smith 82
Jones 75
Washington 91
```

The function should calculate and return the class average from the data in the file.

So far I have:

```
def calc_average():
    infile = open("filename.txt", "r")
    readlines = infile.readlines()
    for line in readlines:
        parts = line.split()
        name = parts[0]
        clsavg = parts[1]
        average = 0
```

I have tried to work past this part, but I can't find the right way to do the average. Any suggestions? I only need the function and the file is only an example.

Comment: you didnt returned anything

Comment: It depends on how data is displayed in the file

Comment: What makes you think you are going wrong? Looks good so far, although you haven't yet done the actual calculating and returning of the average.

Comment: That attempt doesn't look complete. Is there more to the function?

Comment: I was pretty confident in what I have so far, but I can't get past this. Everything I've tried doesn't work past this part.

Comment: I guess what I should really ask is how do I find the average itself. How do I find the sum of the clsavg. I know I must return something once I am done.

Comment: Without an example of your filename.txt it's hard to answer specifically.  If each line in the text has Name, Integer then you can sum all integers (parts[1]) and divide by the number of lines or increment an index and divide by that.

Comment: You will learn more by figuring out how to calculate the average yourself than if someone here gives you the answer. Keep trying. If you need help, talk to a TA or go to your professor's office hours.

Comment: My filename looks exactly how it is formatted in the given example with Smith 82...and so on. New line for each teacher and then a tab in between the name and number.

Answer (score 2):

```
def calc_average():
    infile = open("filename.txt", "r")
    readlines = infile.readlines()
    for line in readlines:
        parts = line.split()
        name = parts[0]
        clsavg = parts[1]
        average = 0
```

After all that, you're just literally sending something into the function, but not asking for anything to come out.

Using `return` will help get something out of the function.

`return [variable]` is a way to use it.

Here:

Add this line
`return [variable]` to the end of your code, such that it looks like this:

```
def calc_average():
    infile = open("filename.txt", "r")
    readlines = infile.readlines()
    for line in readlines:
        parts = line.split()
        name = parts[0]
        clsavg = parts[1]
        average = 0
    return variable #where you replace variable with 
                    #the thing you want to get out of your function
```

To call this function (or should i say "run" it) just write the name of it, but dedented.

```
def calc_average():
    infile = open("filename.txt", "r")
    readlines = infile.readlines()
    for line in readlines:
        parts = line.split()
        name = parts[0]
        clsavg = parts[1]
        average = 0
    return variable
calc_average() #<- this calls the function
```

You might also want to read up on *parameters*:

parametere are values passed into a function and are used.

Example:

```
def test1(number):
    number = number + 1 #this can be written as number += 1 as well
    return number
x = test1(5)
```

First I define the function with a `number` parameter. This would mean that `number` will be used in this function. Notice how the lines below `def test1(number)` also use the variable `number`. whatever is passed into the function as `number` will be considered `number` in the function.

Then, I call the function and use `5` as a parameter.

When it's called, the function takes `5` (since that was the input parameter) and stores the variable `number` as 5.(from `def test1(number)`) Thus, It's like writing `number = 5` in the function itself.

Afterwards, `return number` will take the number (which in this case is added to become 6, `number = 6`) and give it back to the outside code. Thus, it's like saying `return 6`.

Now back to the bottom few lines. `x = test1(5)` will make x = 6, since the function returned 6.

Hope I helped you understand functions more.

Answer (score 0):

The function needs an argument. It also needs to return the average, so there should be a `return` statement at the end.

```
def calc_average(file_name):
    ...
    return <something>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didnt calculated the average.Also didnt return anything from the function `calc_average`.So try this

```
def calc_average():
    with open('filename.txt') as text:
        nums = [int(i.split()[1]) for i in text]
        avg = float(sum(nums)) / float(len(nums))
        return avg
>>>print(calc_average())
82.6666666667
```

Comment: Explaining the thing that you did here would help, since Maddie is new to python.

Answer (score 0):

To continue using mostly your own code and your example, you could do:

```
def calc_average(filename):
    infile = open(filename, "r")
    readlines = infile.readlines()
    average = 0 # use this to sum all grades
    index = 0 # keep track of how many records or lines in our txt
    for line in readlines:
        parts = line.split()
        name = parts[0] # basically useless
        # for each line in txt we sum all grades
        average = average + float(parts[1]) # need to convert this string to a float
        index = index + 1
    # divide by the number of entries in your txt file to get the class average
    return average / index
```

then:

```
calc_average('grades.txt')
```

prints:

```
82.66666666666667
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def calc_average():
    infile = open("filename.txt", "r")
    readlines = infile.readlines()
    clsavg = 0
    counter = 0
    for line in readlines:
        parts = line.split()
        clsavg =  clsavg+ float(parts[1])
        counter = counter + 1
    print clsavg/counter
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, let's look at this, part by part:

> Write a function called calc_average

```
def calc_average():
```

> that takes a string representing a filename

let's make this a meaningful variable name:

```
def calc_average(filename):
```

Now that we have the basics down, let's talk about how to actually solve your problem:

Each line in your file contains a name and a grade. You want to keep track of the grades so that you can compute the average out of them. So, you need to be able to:

1. read a file one line at a time
2. split a line and take the relevant part
3. compute the average of the relevant parts

So, it seems that holding the relevant parts in a list would be helpful. We would then need a function that computes the average of a list of numbers. So let's write that

```
def average(L):
    sum = 0
    for num in L:
        sum += num
    return sum/len(L)
```

Of course, there's an easier way to write this:

```
def average(L):
    return sum(L)/len(L)  # python has a built-in sum function to compute the sum of a list
```

Now that we have a function to compute the average, let's read the file and create a list of numbers whose average we want to compute:

```
def read_from_file(filename):
    answer = []  # a list of all the numbers in the file
    with open(filename) as infile:  # open the file to read
        for line in infile:
            parts = line.split()
            grade = int(parts[-1])  # the integer value of the last entity in that line
            answer.append(grade)
    return answer
```

Now that we have a function that returns the relevant information from a file, and a function that computes averages, we just have to use the two together:

```
def calc_average(filename):
    numbers = read_from_file(filename)
    answer = average(numbers)
    return answer
```

Now, you might notice that you don't need to keep track of each number, as you just sum them up and divide by the number of numbers. So, this can be done more concisely as follows:

```
def calc_average(filename):
    nums = 0
    total = 0
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            total += int(line.split()[-1])
            nums += 1
    return total/nums
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you're doing wrong is not marking the source code in your post, as source code. Put it on separate lines to the rest of your post, and use the `{}` link at the top of the editor to mark it as source code. Then it should come out like this:

```
def calc_average(): 
  infile = open("filename.txt", "r") 
  readlines = infile.readlines() 
  for line in readlines: 
    parts = line.split() 
    name = parts[0] 
    clsavg = parts[1] 
    average = 0
```

You should do the same with the file contents: I am assuming that you have one name and one number per line.

If you want to put a snippet of code inline with your text, e.g. "the `foo()` function", put a backtick each side of the code. The backtick is like an accent grave, and is sometimes very wrongly used as an opening quote char in text files.

Next, you were to write a function that takes a string containing a filename. But you have

```
def calc_average(): 
  infile = open("filename.txt", "r")
```

That doesn't take anything. How about

```
def calc_average(filename): 
  infile = open(filename, "r")
```

Now, what your function is doing is, reading the lines ok, splitting them into a name and a number -- but both are still strings, and the string containing the number is put in the variable `clsavg`, and then just setting the variable `average` to 0 every time a line is read.

But what do you want to do? I think when you say "class average", these are all people in a class, the numbers are their scores, and you want to calculate the average of the numbers? So that means adding up all the numbers, and dividing by the number of rows in the file.

So you need to set a variable to 0 ONCE, before the loop starts, then on each time you read a line, increment it by the number value. I would imagine the clsavg variable would be the one to use. So you need to convert `parts[1]` to an integer. You can use `int()` for that. Then you need to increment it, with `+=` or with a statement like `x = x + y`. Ask google if you want more details. That way you build up a total value of all the numbers. Finally, after the loop is finished (meaning on a line that is only indented as far as the `for`), you need to divide the total by the number of rows. That would be the number of elements in `readlines`. You should google the `len()` function. Division uses the `/` operator. You can use `x /= y` to set x to the value of x/y.

That's making lots of assumptions: that you want an integer average, that every line in the file has the name and number (no blank lines or comments etc.) By the way, you can use `float()` instead of `int()` if you want more precision.